# pd.read_sql then check datatypes results in all columns as "object"?

Tags: python, types

I'm very green to the world of Python and am only on my second ever script. I'm currently using psycopg2 to pull data from a redshift database. It works. However, when I print the dtypes of the data, all columns read as object? Why is this? What am I missing. Here is a code sample...

`data = pd.read_sql("""select * from some.tables, con=credentials)`
`print(data.dtypes)`

The ouput reads as "Column1    Object", "Column2    Object" and so on.

Comment: What are they supposed to be? Can you upload a screenshot of the table?

Comment: 2 feilds are date and the remaining are all string. What I'm trying to get to is I've got to export to an xls file (this file goes to a vendor and xls is the only option). Pandas is dropping xls support at some point so I had to find a workaround. The workaround is using PyExcel. It works. however, the the dates are now formatting as DD/MM/YYYY and I need it in MM/DD/YYYY. Before attempting to learn how to format it, I wanted to check out the datatypes. Just sort of learning these functions as I go along learning Python.